# Ejemplo real de relaciones de orden, reflexiva, antisimétrica, transitiva

Tags: matemáticas, álgebra-relacional

Cómo podemos aplicar relaciones de orden, reflexivas, antisimétricas, transitivas, en una situación real. No encuentro ejemplos reales. Por favor ayudenos. Gracias.